# If ,else and else if statement are not working on button click in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I face a problem when I use if, else, and else if statements. I was making a button Login, there I used that type of code

```
  edtEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
    edtEditText1 = findViewById(R.id.password);
    String email = edtEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = edtEditText1.getText().toString().trim();
    
    btn = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (email.equals("")){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }else if (password.equals("")) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }else {
                signIn();
            }
        }
    });
```

It works only a single line after this line.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: In situations like this, you should use the debugger in Android Studio to see what your code is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code was works.

```
Button signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signup1);
        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String email = edtEditText.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = edtEditText1.getText().toString().trim();
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    edtEditText.setError("Email is Required");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    edtEditText1.setError("Password is Required");
                    return;
                }
                if (password.length() < 5) {
                    edtEditText1.setError("Password will be Minimum 6 Character");
                    return;
                }


                createAccount();
                sendEmailVerification();

            }
```

Comment: A good answer will always include an explanation why this would solve the issue, so that the OP and any future readers can learn from it

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `closure`, the String email is bounded to the value at runtime at setOnClickListener() and is probably the empty string.

You should do this:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = edtEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (email.equals("")){
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    edtEditText = findViewById(R.id.username);
    edtEditText1 = findViewById(R.id.password);
    
    btn = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String email = edtEditText.getText().toString().trim();
            String password = edtEditText1.getText().toString().trim();
            if (email.equals("")){
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }else if (password.equals("")) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }else {
                signIn();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I tried but not work. At last, I found a code that works.

Comment: ok i understand It's works.